# Implementing prox-linear optimizer in PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch

It seems that the PyTorch optimizer class assumes it uses only gradient information. However, I would like to implement a different training algorithm, namely, the prox-linear method, which minimizes losses of the form `g(l(prediction, label))`, where `g` is some known convex function.

The optimizer needs:

- access to the *value* of `l(prediction, label)`, in addition to its gradient w.r.t the parameters
- knowledge of the function `g` beyond its gradient

How should I proceed with designing such an optimizer? How can it gain access to the information it needs?

It is clear that `g`, in some form, should be an argument of the optimizer, and not some generic loss function. But what about `l`?

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you're asking. Is your goal to apply the proximal-operator on your parameters in each `optimizer.step()`? You could have a look at pytorch's implementation of `SGD` (https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/optim/sgd.html#SGD) and build your own `Optimizer` based on that: Nothing stops you from making a parametrized class `ProximalOptimizer(g)` that takes `g` as an argument. You could then use `g` in your update step as you see fit.

Comment: The thing is, that SGD uses gradient information only. How can the step method obtain additional information about the loss, while still adheering to the general contract of the step method of other optimizers?